# TS2339: Property 'featurePolicy' does not exist on type 'Helmet'

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, typescript-typings, helmet.js

I have application with security rules defined by [Helmet](https://github.com/helmetjs/helmet). However, when installing `@types/helmet` I'm getting the following error `TS2339: Property 'featurePolicy' does not exist on type 'Helmet'.`. The code is as follows:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as helmet from 'helmet';
import { Express } from 'express';

const expressApp: Express = express(); // Create Express instance.

// Limit website features by implementing Feature Policy.
expressApp.use(
  helmet.featurePolicy({
    features: {
      fullscreen: ["'self'"],
      payment: ["'none'"],
      syncXhr: ["'none'"]
    }
  })
);
```

Link to Feature Policy, which is part of the Helmet package: https://helmetjs.github.io/docs/feature-policy/

Comment: What if you do const helmet = require('helmet')?

Comment: Are your types and helmet up to date? Feature Policy is pretty new and maybe you have to update your dependencies?

Comment: @stefanjudis version of `helmet` is `3.20.0`, whilst `@types/helmet` is `0.0.43` (fresh installation). I just checked the `index.d.ts` file inside `node_modules/@types/helmet`, and indeed, the `featurePolicy` is missing from the interface `IHelmetConfiguration`.

@Clarity indeed the `const helmet = require('helmet');` solves this problem, but then why is like that?

Comment: @Clarity
PS. But if I'll define a type like so `const helmet: Helmet = require('helmet');` it throws the same error, i.e. `TS2339: Property 'featurePolicy' does not exist on type 'Helmet'.`.

Comment: @DanielDanielecki because if you use `require`, it doesn't go thru typescript compiler.

Comment: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/helmet/index.d.ts#L13-L27 is not up to date. :)

Comment: @Clarity thanks for the answer! It looks like there's no typing for `featurePolicy` at the moment.

Comment: @stefanjudis thanks for the link!
Is anyone of you going to submit an issue about this?

Comment: Nope, go for it. :) the typings are community-driven. I think it's a perfect moment for you to contribute back. :)

Comment: Thank you guys, the issue has been submitted: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/37627